# Check if property of object instance is 'blank'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uilabel, string-comparison

I am trying to implement the code below without success. Basically, I want to set the display name to use `thisPhoto.userFullName` if it is not 'Blank", else show `thisPhoto.userName` instead.

```
UILabel *thisUserNameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kUserNameValueTag];

NSLog(@"user full name %@",thisPhoto.userFullName);
NSLog(@"user name %@",thisPhoto.userName);
if (thisPhoto.userFullName && ![thisPhoto.userFullName isEqual:[NSNull null]] ) 
{
   thisUserNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisPhoto.userFullName];
}
else if (thisPhoto.userFullName == @"")
{
   thisUserNameLabel.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisPhoto.userName];
}
```

Currently, even if `userFullName` is blank, my `userName` is still not displayed on the screen.

Comment: Remember that if you use `==` with objects it compares their pointers. See below for more details on the methods you should use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few points here

First - if your `userFullName` instance variable is `NSString*` then doing simple comparison with `nil` is enough:

```
if (thisPhoto.userFullName)
```

Unless, of course, you explicitly set it to be `[NSNull null]`, which then requires the condition you wrote.

Second - comparing strings is done with `isEqualToString:` method so second condition should be rewritten as:

```
if ([thisPhoto.userFullName isEqualToString:@""]) {
    ...
}
```

Third - there's logic flaw - If your `userFullName` IS equal to empty string (`@""`) the code would still fall to the first branch. I.e. empty string (`@""`) is not equal to `[NSNull null]` or simple nil. Hence you should write to branches - one to handle empty string and nil, other one for normal value. So with a bit of refactoring your code becomes like this:

```
thisUserNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisPhoto.userFullName];
if (!thisPhoto.userFullName || [thisPhoto.userFullName isEqualToString:@""]) {
    // do the empty string dance in case of empty userFullName.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer

```
if([thisPhoto.userFullName length])
```

Comment: I know "zero means false" and "non-zero means true", but this type of code makes me shriek because it makes the intent ambiguous. When someone other than its author looks at that they will say: "Did the author forget to compare that value to another integer?". Omitting the right hand side of the comparison in this case, is IMHO ugly code.

Answer (score 3):

Use `-length`. This will be 0 whenever the string is `nil` or the empty string `@""`. You generally want to treat both cases identically.

```
NSString *fullName = [thisPhoto userFullName];
thisUserNameLabel.text = [fullName length]? fullName : [thisPhoto userName];
```

Answer (score 2):

If, as I suppose, `thisPhoto.userFullName` is a `NSString` you may try

```
[thisPhoto.userFullName isEqualToString:@""]
```

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers are correct, and beat me to it. Rather than just repeat what they have said - I'll point out something else.

`[NSNull null]` is used to store `nil` values in collection classes (`NSArray`, `NSSet`, `NSDictionary`) that don't allow `nil` values to be stored in them.

So unless you're checking values that you get from a collection - there is no point checking against `[NSNull null]`

Answer (score 1):

```
// this assumes userFullName and userName are strings and that userName is not nil
thisUserNameLabel.text = [thisPhoto.userFullName length] > 0 ? thisPhoto.userFullName : thisPhoto.userName;
```

Answer (score 1):

"Blank" means `@""`, but also `@"   "` or `@"\n"`. So I would trim userFullName and check the length of that string.

```
if ([[thisPhoto.userFullName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
        [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {

    // it's blank!
}
```